# How to set ember controller inside a directory?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I have a route defined as follows

```
export default Router.map(function () {

        this.route('home', {path: 'homepage'});
});
```

Normally ember will then load controller named `home` inside controllers folder

But I want to map a controller inside a another directory inside controllers folder. my controller directory is as follows

```
--app
  --controllers
    --homePage
       home.js
```

How can I map route to home.js controller? Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: don't do that! Maybe the `pods` structure or `ember-engines` is what you are actually looking for? If not, stay with the convention. Really!

Long version: You would have to override the `Resolver`. Checkout the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.DefaultResolver.html) and know [this](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-resolver/blob/master/addon/resolver.js) is the resolver used for `ember-cli`.